# Iterating a list in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a "line" in my 2D array and for some reason it's not working. I don't get any error, but for some reason it's not doing what I wanted.

Here's the code:

```
#Create arrays
t = []
for x in range(10):
    t.append([])
    for y in range(10):
        t[x].append("x")

#Create line
for x in t[7]:
    x = "_"

#Print grid
for x in t:
    o = ""
    for y in x:
        o += str(y) + " "
    print(o)
```

The output should look something like this:

```
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
```

But looks like this:

```
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x
```

I'm sure I've made some stupid mistake, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
#Create line
for x in t[7]:
    x = "_"
```

In this `for` loop, `x` is only a local variable. If you change `x`, it has no effect on the list `t[7]`. You need to do this instead:

```
#Create line
for i, x in enumerate(t[7]):
    t[7][i] = "_"
```